# Transparent/no background color in borderPane

Tags: java, css, javafx, javafx-8, borderpane

I'm trying to build my own loading dialog. I have an .*png which represent the loading-indicator. This image will be set in imageview wrapped in a borderpane. My problem is that the borderpane background refuse to get transparent. I have tried serveral options but nothing works out like I desire. I have tried to set the background directly in FXML but also in Javacode and CSS. Nothing works.

This problem appeared when I updated to Java 1.8_77 frin 1.8_66. I googled it but didnt find anything about this.

Does anybody knows why this doesn't work?

I have tried with:

**CSS**

```
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-background-color: none;
-fx-background-color: transparent !important;
-fx-background-color: rgba
```

**Java**

```
borderPane.setBackground(Background.EMPTY);
borderPane.getScene().setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
borderPane.getScene().getRoot().setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent !important;");
```

**FXML**
*same as CSS*

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]?